# How to find the mean of values in a column for rows with specific values in another column in R?

Tags: r

How do I find the mean of the score column values but only when country is equal to Albania in the R language?

```
  country year     score        
 Algeria 1980     -1.1201501 
 Algeria 1981     -1.0526943 
 Albania 1982     -1.0561565 
 Algeria 1983     -1.1274560 
 Algeria 1984     -1.1353926 
 Algeria 1985     -1.1734330 
 Albania 1986     -1.1327666 
 Algeria 1987     -1.1263586 
 Algeria 1988     -0.8529455 
 Algeria 1989     -0.2930265 
 Albania 1990     -0.1564207 
 Algeria 1991     -0.1526328 
 Algeria 1992     -0.9757842 
 Algeria 1993     -0.9714060
```

Comment: There must be at least ten, maybe twenty versions of this question already answered. Please do some searching and if failing to find an answer, then post the failing strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is named `df` you can try

```
with(df, mean(score[country == "Albania"]))
```

you could also use one of these

```
with(df, tapply(score, country, mean)) 
aggregate(score~country, data=df, mean )
```

to calculate the mean in each `country`.